# RDP or VNC in browser

Tags: windows, rdp, vnc

Is anyone aware of good, usable and FREE (for commercial use) in-browser solutions to connect to a Windows server? I can't seem to find any inbrowser RDP. There seems to be some VNC based solutions (Guacamole?, terms unclear) and I can't tell if they're worth a shot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309094/which-flash-ajax-based-vnc-viewer-do-you-recommend

Comment: Guacamole VNC uses the AGPLv3. noVNC uses LGPLv3.

Comment: `noVNC` and `Guacamole` are the top 2 options on my mind. But I only succeeded in configuring `noVNC` on my box.

Answer (score 4):

[noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) requires the HTML5 canvas and websockets and is licensed under LGPL.

Comment: So in a nutshell, it's completely unusable in any browser today ;-) (especially given that Websockets support has been removed everywhere recently)

Comment: @Joey, no. All browsers apart from IE have supported Canvas for a long time (and IE 9 will have good support). Also, noVNC includes web-socket-js (Flash fallback) for browsers without support or for browsers where it has been temporarily disabled until the security issues with the handshake are addressed in the draft standard.

Comment: I did indeed refer to websockets, not canvas. But good to know that there is a fallback (and the statement in the answer is false).

Answer (score 2):

You also have Steemind (http://www.steemind.com) which run on all browsers (even IE6), but it's  not free also

Answer (score 1):

ThinVNC has a free version (also valid for commercial use) which allows you to connect to any Windows version and edition (XP, 2003, 2008, Vista, Seven - Home, Proffessional, Enterprise, Ultimate, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can try ThinRDP, which is an HTML5 solution to connect to Windows, Terminal Server, or Linux running xRDP. It's not free though.

Answer (score 0):

This should go to superuser.

However I think UltraVNC support inbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Windows [supports this natively](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/tips/xp_rd_web.htm) for RDP as of Windows XP.

Comment: [Remote Desktop Web Connection](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/mobility/getstarted/webconoverview.mspx) uses an ActiveX control so it's non portable to other OS's or browsers.

Comment: @kanaka The question is tagged "Windows".

Comment: sure, but the question is asking about connecting to a **Windows server**. @Mariam did not specify the client OS or which browser. One of the advantages of using a client in a browser is portability. For example, she might want a browser solution for using on both her iPhone and in Chrome on her **Windows** laptop. In which case Remote Desktop Web Connection would be the wrong answer. Therefore it's worth noting that Remote Desktop Web Connection requires ActiveX and is non-portable.

Comment: @kanaka: Fair enough. It's still a native, ready-made solution for a huge chunk of the use case market share though. :)